Why is there a $\delta$ in the inequality in big Rudin 9.5
9.5 Theorem
For any function $f$ on $R^1$ and every $y \in R^1$, let $f_y$ be the translate off defined by
$$
f_y(x)=f(x-y) \quad\left(x \in R^1\right) .
$$
If $1 \leq p<\infty$ and if $f \in L^p$, the mapping
$$
y \rightarrow f_y
$$
is a uniformly continuous mapping of $R^1$ into $L^p\left(R^1\right)$.
Proof. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Since $f \in L^p$, there exists a continuous function $g$ whose support lies in a bounded interval $[-A, A]$, such that
$$
\|f-g\|_p<\epsilon
$$
(Theorem 3.14). The uniform continuity of $g$ shows that there exists a $\delta \in(0, A)$ such that $|s-t|<\delta$ implies
$$
|g(s)-g(t)|<(3 A)^{-1 / p} \epsilon .
$$
If $|s-t|<\delta$, it follows that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|g(x-s)-g(x-t)|^p d x<(3 A)^{-1} \epsilon^p(2 A+\delta)<\epsilon^p,
$$
so that $\left\|g_s-g_t\right\|_p<\epsilon$.
Note that $L^p$-norms (relative to Lebesgue measure) are translationinvariant: $\|f\|_p=\left\|f_s\right\|_p$. Thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left\|f_s-f_t\right\|_p & \leq\left\|f_s-g_s\right\|_p+\left\|g_s-g_t\right\|_p+\left\|g_t-f_t\right\|_p \\
& =\left\|(f-g)_s\right\|_p+\left\|g_s-g_t\right\|_p+\left\|(g-f)_t\right\|_p<3 \epsilon
\end{aligned}
$$
whenever $|s-t|<\delta$. This completes the proof.
My Question.
Since $|s-t|<\delta $, we have $|(x-s)-(x-t)|<\delta $. Thus $|g(x-s)-(x-t)|<\epsilon $. I think the $\delta$ in the inequality is redundant. How can I get that $\delta$ in the inequality?

The $\delta$ is chosen so that $|g(x-s)-g(x-t)|<(3 A)^{-1 / p} \epsilon$ holds for all $x\in\Bbb R$, whose existence is guaranteed the by uniform continuity of $g$. The reason why the coefficient $(3A)^{-1/p}$ is present is I think the author wants to arrive at a neat estimate in the end ($<3\epsilon$ in this case).

@Vim I think it is because the interval of the integral is enlarged.

The coefficient is chosen to cancel out the other coefficient arising from estimating the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|g(x-s)-g(x-t)|^p \mathrm d x$. Anyway, it is not crucial to the problem.

According to the sign of $t-s$, the support of the map $x\mapsto \lvert g(x-s)-g(x-t)\rvert$ is contained either in $[-A-\delta,A]$ or in $[-A,A+\delta]$ (but not necessarily in $[-A,A]$) and both set have measure $2A+\delta$, which explains why this term appears.
